# Median for all numeric and mode for all characters in R

Tags: r, dplyr

With a dataset like **original**:

```
id <- c("JF", "GH", "GH", "ANN", "GH", "ROG", "JF")
group <- c("most", "least", "most", "least", "least", "most", "least")
NP <- c(4,6,18,1,3,12,8)
iso_USA <- c(1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1)
iso_CHN <- c(0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0)
color <- c("blue", "orange", "blue", "blue", "red", "orange", "black")

original <- data.frame(id, group, NP, iso_USA, iso_CHN, color)


numeric <- unlist(lapply(original, is.numeric))  
numeric <- names(original[ , numeric])

char <- unlist(lapply(original, is.character))  
char <- names(original[ , char])
char <- char[-1]   #remove id from variables of interest
```

I want to **group by "group"** and calculate the **median for the numeric variables** and the **mode for the character variables**. Therefore, the data looks like **original2**. Note that my actual dataset has way more columns than the mock version presented here:

```
group <- c("least", "most")
NP <- c(6,12)
iso_USA <- c(0,1)
iso_CHN <- c(0, 0)
color <- c("orange", "blue")

original2 <- data.frame(group, NP, iso_USA, iso_CHN, color)
```

Any clue?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using `dplyr`'s `across` functionality and the the accepted answer [at the FAQ about implementing a `mode` function](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8189441/903061):

```
Mode <- function(x) {
  ux <- unique(x)
  ux[which.max(tabulate(match(x, ux)))]
}

library(dplyr)
original %>%
  select(-id) %>%
  group_by(group) %>%
  summarize(
    across(where(is.numeric), median),
    across(where(is.character), Mode)
  )
# # A tibble: 2 × 6
#   group    NP iso_USA iso_CHN color 
#   <chr> <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl> <chr> 
# 1 least   4.5       0       0 orange
# 2 most   12         1       0 blue
```

Comment: How can you omit NA values?

Comment: `across(where(is.numeric), median, na.rm = TRUE)`. See my linked FAQ for a few different `Mode` implementations, some of which handle missing values.

Comment: Thank you, Gregor!

Answer (score 2):

Here's a **base R** solution.

Little **EDIT** (thx @Gergor Thomas for your valuable input)

For this I also need

<strike>* a function that can tell me if elements are castable to numeric
and - obviously -</strike>

- a *Mode* function (which I will copy blatantly from @Gregor Thomas's solution).

```
Mode <- function(x){ ux <- unique(x)
  ux[which.max(tabulate(match(x, ux)))] }
```

##### Usage

```
aggregate( original[,3:6], by=list(original$group), function(x){ 
  'if'( is.numeric(x),median(x),Mode(x) ) } )

  Group.1   NP iso_USA iso_CHN  color
1   least  4.5       0       0 orange
2    most 12.0       1       0   blue
```

Comment: Thank you for your intellectual curiosity and proposal!

Comment: @GregorThomas All true and I agree. I also played around with finding a more performant solution. It's actually approx 3 times slower than your dplyr solution. The regex did boil down to avoiding the warnings `as.numeric` returns. In a different scenario I'd actually choose speed over "beauty". I included the cast because in this case aggregate treats the number columns as character.

Comment: @GregorThomas Godammit, I hate when I am so deep in a rabbit hole to not see the obvious... :) well thanks! In that case I might switch to using the `'data.frame'` version of aggregate.

Comment: @GregorThomas Now 6 times faster than dplyr, but of course that's a reasonable price to pay for readability, as you pointed out.

Comment: @GregorThomas Interesting, good to know... I actually did it with a 100k rows, 100 cols version of the example data. Thx!!

Comment: The number of groups makes a big difference for scalability - that's where `dplyr` beats `base` (and where `data.table` really shines).

Comment: @GregorThomas Yep, `data.table` is a beast. Thanks for your insights!!

Comment: Fun discussion :) I am going to delete most of my comments here, I don't think they need to preserved on SO.