# Calculate averages of imputed data in mice

Tags: r, imputation, r-mice

I would like to calculate the individual-level averages of the imputed datasets in Mice (for presentational purposes, not for analysis). For example, if I have the following dataset with missing.

| Id | V1 | V2 | V3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 10 | NA | 9 |
| 2 | 12 | 8 | NA |
| 3 | NA | 7 | 11 |

And 2 imputed datasets like these (imputed values marked with *)

| Id | V1 | V2 | V3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 10 | 10* | 9 |
| 2 | 12 | 8 | 12* |
| 3 | 11* | 7 | 11 |

| Id | V1 | V2 | V3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 10 | 9* | 9 |
| 2 | 12 | 8 | 10* |
| 3 | 14* | 7 | 11 |

I would like the resulting dataset look like this, with * numbers being the averages of the imputed missing data.

| Id | V1 | V2 | V3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 10 | 9.5* | 9 |
| 2 | 12 | 8 | 11* |
| 3 | 12.5* | 7 | 11 |

I can't figure out how to do this in an effective way in R.

Comment: `df[is.na(df)] <- ((df1 + df2)/2)[is.na(df)]`

Answer (score 0):

You can dirrectly replace the NA values:

```
 df[is.na(df)] <- ((impute_df1 + imput_df2)/2)[is.na(df)]
```

Comment: Elegant. I do however have 100 imputed datasets - can this be easily generalized to any number of imputations?

Comment: @DrLjotsson yes. are your imputed `dfs` in a list??

Comment: I can combine them into a list

Comment: @DrLjotsson Yes you got it.

Comment: @DrLjotsson and once you have the whole averages, just do `df[is.na(df)] <- averages[is.na(averages)]`

Answer (score 0):

I brute-forced it.

```
averages <- complete(imp, 1)
for(m in 2:imp$m){
  averages <- averages + complete(imp, m)
}
averages <- averages / imp$m
```

Answer (score 0):

Given that all variables are continuous, consider using `Reduce`:

```
lapply(1:imp$m, function(x) complete(imp, x)) %>% {Reduce(`+`, .) /length(.)}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're using `mice` to deal with missing values, it is wrong to directly take the averages of the imputed values from `n` sets of data. As Manon Grevinga and Stef van Buuren discussed in their tutorial, this brute-force method will lead to wrong estimation. See: [II: Multiple imputation using mice](https://stefvanbuuren.name/RECAPworkshop/Practicals/RECAP_Practical_II.html)

Answer (score 0):

The average imputed value at the cell-level can easily be computed for numeric variables. The code below also calculates the mode for factors/character variables. The calculation of the mode was adapted from https://stackoverflow.com/a/70190167/17724015

```r
# packages and function for mode
library(mice, warn.conflicts = FALSE)
library(dplyr, warn.conflicts = FALSE)
Mode <- function(x) {
  ux <- unique(x)
  ux[which.max(tabulate(match(x, ux)))]
}

# imputation
imp <- mice(boys, printFlag = FALSE)

# cell-wise average
long <- complete(imp, "long")
long %>%
  select(-.imp) %>%
  group_by(.id) %>%
  summarize(
    across(where(is.numeric), mean),
    across(where(is.character), Mode)
  ) %>% 
  select(-.id)
#> # A tibble: 748 × 6
#>      age   hgt   wgt   bmi    hc    tv
#>    <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#>  1 0.035  50.1  3.65  14.5  33.7   2.4
#>  2 0.038  53.5  3.37  11.8  35     2.6
#>  3 0.057  50    3.14  12.6  35.2   4.2
#>  4 0.06   54.5  4.27  14.4  36.7   2  
#>  5 0.062  57.5  5.03  15.2  37.3   2.4
#>  6 0.068  55.5  4.66  15.1  37     2  
#>  7 0.068  52.5  3.81  13.8  34.9   2.4
#>  8 0.071  53    3.89  13.8  35.8   2  
#>  9 0.071  55.1  3.88  12.8  36.8   2.4
#> 10 0.073  54.5  4.2   14.1  38     2.4
#> # ℹ 738 more rows
```

<sup>Created on 2023-11-20 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

PS. The cell-wise averages should *not* be used for inference. As a general rule, imputations are not to be aggregated. Instead, one should pool the analysis estimates.